# socket file descriptor changes automatically

Tags: c, sockets, networking, file-descriptor

I tried to capture all the UDP packets approaching my NIC using RAW socket programming. Here I am getting a strange problem. While my program is running my socket descriptor changes itself automatically. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main () {

int sockfd = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (sockfd < 0) {
    perror ("socket failed");
    return -1;
}

char *buf = malloc (8192);
memset (buf, 0, 8192);
if (!buf) {
    perror ("calloc failed\n");
    return -1;
}

int ret_recv;
i:
while ((ret_recv = recv (sockfd, buf, 8192, 0)) > -1) {
    printf ("%d\n", ret_recv);
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) buf;
    //struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr *) (buf + sizeof (struct iphdr));
    struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *) (buf + sizeof (struct iphdr));
    char ip[4];
    printf ("source ip: %s\n", inet_ntop (AF_INET, &iph->saddr, ip, sizeof (struct sockaddr_in)));
    printf ("dest ip: %s\n", inet_ntop (AF_INET, &iph->daddr, ip, sizeof (struct sockaddr_in)));
    //printf ("port: %d\n", ntohs (udph->source));
    printf ("port: %d\n", ntohs (tcph->source));
}
perror ("recv failed");
//goto i;
return 0;
}
```

In my output, instead of a infinite loop of packet information printing, only one packet of information is being printed. So I have checked with the gdb. I used `display sockfd`. After socket call, the value of the sockfd was 7. Then inside the while loop, after executing the printf of dest ip, the sockfd value changed to 808988216. So the recv failed with a "bad file descriptor" error. I can't find what actually went wrong.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Did you run your program with valgrind? My guess is that you're corrupting the stack inside the while {}. BTW change char ip[4] to inet_ntop to ip[16] or better to ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]

Comment: Memory corruption at it best. Check your pointer arithmetic.

Comment: The code posted is correct as it is. I suspect it's not the real code (you're probably omitting something thinking "This can't be it").

Comment: Why are you checking the result of `malloc()` *after* you use it? And why are you printing 'calloc failed' when you are calling `malloc()`, not `calloc()`? And why are you calling `malloc()` and `memset()` when calling `calloc()` would have done both, and made your debug printout correct? And why are you using `struct tcphdr *` to look at UDP packets?

Comment: @EJP: initially I used calloc. Later I changed it with malloc and memset. But forgot to edit the printout ;-). And I used tcphdr structure for udphdr structure. Actually I accessed only the source port. In both udphdr and tcphdr, the first field is same, mentioning the source port address. So it will not make any difference in this program. I am just learning. This is one of my trail programs. So please don't expect standard here. :-)

Comment: I could have guessed all that. Indeed I did. The reason for the questions is to improve your code, and to make you think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a buffer overflow:

```
char ip[4];
    printf ("source ip: %s\n", inet_ntop (AF_INET, &iph->saddr, ip, sizeof (struct sockaddr_in)));
```

The buffer is not large enough to hold the string form of the IP address. Also, the fourth argument is lying to `inet_ntop()` about the available space, it should be:

```
char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
printf ("source ip: %s\n", inet_ntop (AF_INET, &iph->saddr, ip, sizeof ip));
```